# Design Database Entity and Relations

Tags: sql, database

I want to create website to organize events (Events Management), the event organizer will create tickets for the event.. so the idea behind this is to give organizer the ability to manage their crowd and capacity.

User can review and rate the event and write a comment, maybe also ticket cancellation and i need him have ability to browse events based on city or calendar.

So i designed my database like this but i think it needs for more enhancement before i continue. I really need your help.

User Table
Id, Name, Email, Password, Gender, Mobile

Role Table
RoleID, Name (here i mean id 1 for admin, 2 for organizer, 3 for user)

Event Table
EventID, Name, Category, City, Date, Time, Description, Seats(Capacity)

Rating Table
ID, Rating, Comment, EventID, UserID

there is relation between User and Role Tables N:1 
there is relation between User and Event Tables M:N

How should I make relation for rating table? is it with two tables (USER & EVENT)? WHAT TYPE OF RELATION?

Any suggestion in all tables?

Answer (score 0):

You can structure the database like this

1. Role Table
   RoleId|RoleName
2. User Table
   UserId|**RoleId**|Name|Email|Password|Gender|Mobile
3. Event Table
   EventId|**UserId**|Name|Category|City|Date|Time|Description|Seats(Capacity)
4. Rating Table
   RatingId|**EventId**|**UserId**|Comment

I have highlighted column names which are having foreign key relation. Let me know if this helps.

Comment: what about rating table, i need USERID FIELD TWICE one for the user who will rate and the other id for the OrganizerID who will be rated.. IS IT OKEY?

Comment: Event Table is having UserId who creates/organize an event and that EventId will be used in Rating Table so automatically you are getting Organizer UserId as well as UserId of the user who is rating event. Hope this helps!

Comment: but how i can represent it in ER DIAGRAM? I MEAN THE RELATION BETWEEN RATING TABLE AND OTHER?

Comment: You can show the relationship between these entities like:- Role Table and User table is having 1-1 relationship. and User table and event table is having 1 -M relationship

Comment: Adding to @ShwetaKhude answer. You will be managing WHAT and HOW you will see your data by means of INNER JOIN queries. Good Database Normalization though. :)